# Getting started with react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-cli

I am starting react-native for developing android and ios app. I have followed [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) tutorial for getting started.
The react version **"react": "16.8.6",** was installed. I tried couple of basics and it worked. But while trying to develop some real stuff, I cannot find single example where only react-native is used. They instruct me to use "expo"

In facebook documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button), they use expo-constants.

```
  import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

The question is react dependent with expo ? I could try building with expo too, but it I read somewhere that it has some limitation.
For now I am trying to make simple app in react-native without using expo, where can i find the appropriate documentation ?

In addition I tried making side-menu using

- DrawerNavigator and
- StackNavigator

as described in [this](https://reactnativecode.com/drawer-navigator-with-custom-sidebar-menu/) tutorial, but i get error saying **undefined is not a function ** which is pointing to the following line of code

const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = StackNavigator({

The code goes like this

```
    const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    First: {
        screen: MainActivity,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'MainActivity',
        headerLeft: <HamburgerIcon navigationProps={navigation} />,

        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#FF9800'
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        })
    },
    });
```

later I found that **StackNavigator** now is not present in "react-navigation". I got pretty confused. Could anyone please provide me any way to start fresh in react-native-cli without using expo or any other. Or is it necessary to use expo in react-native-cli too ?
If I could find a sample application including all the building blocks of an application I could understand it better. Thanks to you all.
Any kinds of help are highly appreciated.

Comment: About stackNavigator it's not StackNavigator but createStackNavigator

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create plain React Native apps, but I'd really recommend you to use the expo-cli. It's simpler and you can do more with less work.

About your navigator problem.
Do it like this:

```html
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

createStackNavigator(RouteConfigs, StackNavigatorConfig);

createStackNavigator({
   First: {
    screen: MainActivity,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'MainActivity',
    headerLeft: <HamburgerIcon navigationProps={navigation} />,

    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800'
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    })
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, would there be any problem later using expo cli?  Also thats just a chunk of code, could you please provide a sample of side menu for this time? Just a simple sample but a complete code. Thank you sir

Comment: @SuzAannshrestha no there would be no problem using the expo-cli. What you are searching for is a Drawer Navigator. You can find a sample code here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html